# Case Value Statement

Tags: mysql, sql

The below query gives the result i.e wherever value1 is there changes into changeValue1

```
select case 1 when person ="value1" then "changeValue1"
              when person="value2" then "changeValue2" 
              else person end as nickname
from person;
```

Below query is not changing the value1 and value2 to corresponding "then" value

```
select case 2 when person ="value1" then "changeValue1"
              when person="value2" then "changeValue2" 
              else person end as nickname
from person;
```

I know its only because of case 1 and case2.Can anybody explain me how this function is working

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/case.html

Comment: http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/control-flow-functions/case-operator.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### General notes

There are 2 types of cases: with a value after CASE and without it.

1. `CASE value WHEN [compare_value] THEN result [WHEN [compare_value] THEN result ...] [ELSE result] END`

It compares the value after case with a list of possible values:

```
mysql> SELECT CASE 1 WHEN 1 THEN 'one'
    ->     WHEN 2 THEN 'two' ELSE 'more' END;
        -> 'one'
```

This version compares the value after case with values, given after `WHEN`.

`2.` `CASE WHEN [condition] THEN result [WHEN [condition] THEN result ...] [ELSE result] END`

```
mysql> SELECT CASE WHEN 1>0 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END;
        -> 'true'
```

This version will return the value after the first true condition.

As you are using the 2-nd version, you don't need to put 1 or 2.

### Investigating, how your code works

In your case you get the correct result for 1 as it tries to cast the 2-nd type query to the 1-st type. It evaluates the expressions and compares the result with 1. 1 and TRUE is the same value, that's why it works.

When you type 2, it always goes to ELSE branch, because 2 is neither TRUE or FALSE. If you try to set 0 instead of 2, it will give you the result of the first false expression:

```
mysql> SELECT CASE 0 WHEN 2<0 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END;
+----------------------------------------------+
| CASE 0 WHEN 2<0 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END |
+----------------------------------------------+
| true                                         |
+----------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's not working is that you are comparing an integer with a boolean, which in mysql is either `1` or `0` - never `2`.

There are two forms of the case statement. The first form is like this:

```
case when condition then value1
     when condition1 then value2
     else value3 end
```

the second is like this, more like a `switch` in C/java:

```
case col
    when `foo` then value1
    when `bar` then value2
    else value3 end
```

You're trying to use the second form, comparing `2` with the boolean result of `person="changeValue1", which in mysql is`1`for`true`and`0`for`false`.

Try this instead:

```
case person
    when "value1" then "changeValue1"
    when "value2" then "changeValue2"
    else person
end
```

If you're trying to use the first form, just remove the `2`:

```
case when person ="value1" then "changeValue1"
     when person="value2" then "changeValue2" 
     else person end as nickname
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `person='something` can be `true` or `false`, which is compared to `1` which is equivalent to `true` value.

It will also work with `true` instead of `1`.

```
select case true when person ="value1" then "changeValue1"
              when person="value2" then "changeValue2" 
              else person end as nickname
from person;
```

Or anything equivalent to `true` like:

```
select case 'something'='something' when person ="value1" then "changeValue1"
              when person="value2" then "changeValue2" 
              else person end as nickname
from person;
```

Finally, it works just like if-else condition.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing the two [available syntaxes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/case.html). As per the manual:

> ```
> CASE case_value
>     WHEN when_value THEN statement_list
>     [WHEN when_value THEN statement_list] ...
>     [ELSE statement_list]
> END CASE
> ```
>
> `case_value` is an expression. This value is compared to the
>   `when_value` expression in each `WHEN` clause until one of them is
>   equal. When an equal `when_value` is found, the corresponding `THEN`
>   clause statement_list executes. If no `when_value` is equal, the
>   `ELSE` clause statement_list executes, if there is one.

Since you provide an expression (either `1` or `2`) they get compared with the `WHEN` expressions until there's a match, but those are expressions themselves so they get evaluated to `0` or `1`. That's why the second one can never have a match: `2` will always be different to `0` or `1`.

Your initial expression servers no purpose here. You want one of these:

```
select case
    when person="value1" then "changeValue1"
    when person="value2" then "changeValue2" 
    else person
end as nickname
from person;

select case person 
    when "value1" then "changeValue1"
    when "value2" then "changeValue2" 
    else person
end as nickname
from person;
```